# jquery load modal if one hour passed

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, time

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#bb').modal();
});
```

I am loading a bootstrap modal on load. But i don't want to show modal on every load. It should be like "show if 60 minutes passed after previous load".

I can't log ip addresses because all of users are using the same ip address.

Can i do this with jquery only (it can be like "show if time is first 5 minutes of hour")?

If not what are my other options?

Comment: I use jQuery and check the time with cookies.

Comment: Use user SESSION at your PHP ... store there 1 key (last_time) equal to current time. And on each 1 hour difference set at your PHP to be loaded your Javascript modal and update that session key to current time..

Comment: Well, do you want *"show if 60 minutes passed after previous load"* or *"show if time is first 5 minutes of hour"*? (Those are **different** requirements with **different** answers.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I want to make first if it is possible with basic things, if not i will make second. So i want answers for both. Trying jquery cookies now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want, however you might want to consider reloading your content async rather than always driving off document.ready()

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function getCookie(c_name)
{
var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
  {
  x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
  y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
  x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
  if (x==c_name)
    {
    return unescape(y);
    }
  }
}

function setCookie(c_name,value,exminutes)
{
var exdate=new Date();
exdate.setMinutes(exdate.getMinutes() + exminutes);
var c_value=escape(value) + ((exminutes==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function checkCookie()
{
var lastload=getCookie("lastload");

if (lastload!=null && lastload!="")
  {
    // no need to do anything
  }
else 
  {
    // show / load modal
  }
  setCookie("lastload",1,60);
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="checkCookie()">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Additionally note that I put the setCookie("lastload",1,60); outside the if statement so that it is always called, this will have the affect of always resetting the lastload cookie, this may or may not be desirable. You might want to move it inside the else.

Answer (score 4):

You could set a cookie with an expiration of 60 minutes und check if the cookie is still present. If it is not, you show your modal again.

There is a nice jQuery Cookie Plugin [here](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie).

If you don't set the expiration date of the cookie to 60 Minutes or if that is not possible at all, you could store the time the cookie was created inside of the cookie and check if this time is >= 60 Minutes from your current time. If so, you display the modal and refresh the cookie time.

Answer (score 1):

You have a Date() object in javascript. Check the time in your code. If its first 5 mins of the hour display modal. Else don't display the modal.

```
var date = new Date();
if(date.getMinutes()<=5)
{
   // display
}
else{
    // Dont display
}
```

Comment: And if user reload page 100 times in those 5 minutes ?

Comment: Doesn't work for every user separately, but for all with the same amount of time.